# Ionic Framework - $ionicLoading: How to display both spinner and label?

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework

I don't see an option to display both spinner and label message!
[Docs](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicLoading/).

Is there a simple way to do this or it must be something that I have to do myself?

Example (it doesn't have to look like this of course): http://www.jqueryscript.net/images/jQuery-Ajax-Loading-Overlay-with-Loading-Text-Spinner-Plugin.jpg

Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can try this:

```
$ionicLoading.show({
  template: '<ion-spinner></ion-spinner> <br/> My Label'
});
```

Not tested, I think it will show up the spinner, but maybe no animation.

Comment: Thanks a lot, simple solution and it works perfectly!

Comment: You're welcome! But in my last month project, the spinner doesn't spin. Did your spinner spin?

Comment: Yes it's working perfectly here. Did you implement the exactly same thing?

Comment: Wow, I've open up my project and implement the exacly same thing, it's spinning now ^^.

Answer (score 5):

You can load your template:

```
<script id="loading.html" type="text/ng-template">
    <ion-spinner icon="bubbles"></ion-spinner>
    <p>LOADING...</p>
</script>
```

and in your code:

```
$ionicLoading.show({
      templateUrl: 'loading.html'
      // noBackdrop: true
    });
```

or, as [Nam Pham](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5480251/nam-pham) suggested, defined an inline template:

```
$ionicLoading.show({
      template: '<ion-spinner icon="bubbles"></ion-spinner><p>LOADING...</p>'
      // noBackdrop: true
    });
```

If you want you can defined a different [spinner](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionSpinner/).

You can see how it works [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jbxWoP?editors=101).

Comment: Thanks a lot, I marked  Nam's answer as correct because he was first. But again thanks for your help!

Comment: I accept that. Nam's answer was good and the first one. He deserves it. Cheers.